# What are the advantages of converting empty strings to evaluate to true as compared to false?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, language-features, boolean

When converting a string to a boolean, what are the advantages of having a programming language evaluate an empty string as true and what are the advantages of having it evaluate it to false?

Comment: Could you specify the language where you're doing this? It certainly isn't universal.

Comment: @MichaelT: it's not universal, but not uncommon either. Most languages that *allow* non-boolean-to-boolean conversion treat the empty string as false-ish.

Comment: The idea to consider an empty string false is false.

Comment: Common Lisp treats empty strings as true ( http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Empty_string#Common_Lisp )

Comment: "... empty string is equivalent to true in Ruby" ( http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Empty_string#Ruby )

Comment: The point I was trying to make with that is that the design decisions for each language as to why empty string is a given truth value are different.  One cannot just say ask the broad question.  Perl has different design decisions than javascript or ruby.

Comment: @MichaelT: fair enough, the information you posted here could easily make an answer ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer it might be, but I still don't know what the actual problem of the question is.  I can't answer the general case because its not universal at all. I could answer explain it for ruby (quite simple - only false and nil are falsy - everything else is truthy). But that doesn't answer the question and many other answers are possible for other languages.

Comment: got to say, i consider all the answers so far that refer to this being 'useful' are completely wrongheaded.   Implicit conversions like this are confusing, lack portability, reduce maintainability, and verge on intentional obfuscation.  Hiding complexity behind built-in 'tricks' of each language is clever at first and devastating later.  if the subject is complex, like str can be undefined type, str can be null, str can be defined, not null, but blank, YOU the programmer must be explicit how you want deal with this. at the point of usage. not buried in some docs on the JavaScript API.

Comment: The question is about why empty strings are considered false, not on the merits of implicit conversions. In order to explain this, we have to explain why there are implicit conversions in the first place and I don't agree that it's wrongheaded to explain this. I'd like to note as well that you don't have to opt into using the implicit conversions. Nobody's suggesting that you go out and use them exclusively. Also "portability" only matters if you're converting code between languages, and then you'd have much bigger problems than implicit conversions anyway.

Comment: Updated with the language I was thinking of and a clarification of the question.

Comment: -1: Any question such as this can be adequately answered by exploring the "why not" response.

Comment: @Joel the answer to 'why they are considered false' is sure to include references to some benefit, and therefore the analysis of the presumed benefits of implicit conversion is entirely applicable.  if you can think of a specific, mechanical, computational, reason why this might be better i'm all ears

Comment: @Joel portability doesn't have to be hard.  if you have written your code to not depend on tricks, but to subscribe to a deeper, more generalized approach to considering primitives, primitives that are actually known mathematical primitives. EG ask a mathematician whether you can convert a 4 x 4 matrix to a boolean.

Comment: @mattnz If that was the case, then the feature wouldn't exist. You'd be answering the question "why isn't an empty string considered false" - but it is considered false, so it's a premise that's already been thrown out. I agree that it's important to understand judicious application of operator overloading in general, but I'm assuming that the asker understands the tool itself and is curious about this design decision and the tradeoffs. Perhaps that's the difference.

Comment: @Joel go ahead and discuss this, but my use of wrongheaded refers to the characterization of this technique as 'useful'.

Comment: Php inherited its "" is false from perl.  Perl inherited it from awk.  Awk defined true as "In awk, any non-zero numeric value, or any non-empty string value is true." and then everything else as false. There's the design decisions for php.

Comment: @MichaelT this is almost like Regular expressions where in almost makes sense to have a strings converted to booleans implicitly.  i think, because like in Lisp, there is a almost baked-in-design pattern that is built for breaking apart symbols or strings until there are no more.  In this, highly script-like and loose language paradigm, i can see how it would be expressive to be able to say *for ( str )* or something and it would just automatically parse the list and spit out the pieces in the iterator yield, and when the string is 'done' the string itself kinda evaluates to false.

Comment: @mattnz The "why not" response was also part of my question. I wanted to know why AND why not.  I wanted both sides of the issue and never stated my opinion about which way is best.  So why did you downvote?  Are you saying it's entirely arbitrary?

Answer (score 5):

In the context of JavaScript (I'm guessing this is what generated the question), an empty string evalutes to false in a boolean context because it allows you to use the pattern `if (str)`. If an empty string didn't evaluate to false (along with other states like `null` or `undefined`), you would have to do the following: `if (typeof str !== "undefined" && str != null && str !== "")`.

This is far more verbose.

An alternate interpretation is that the default state of a primitive evaluates to false. For booleans, this is false. For integers, this is 0. For strings, that would be an empty string. Conceptually, there's no guarantee of nulls existing in a given type system, a value should have a default state.

Comment: There is no guarantee of "default states" existing in a given type system either...

Answer (score 3):

Converting a string to boolean true or false and other implicit conversions are charterized thusly...

The advantages: possibly more succinct,clever looking code; possibly some more fluidity and expressiveness when writing code quickly; maybe good for quick and loose prototypeing or scripting

are easily outweighted by the

Disadvantages: confusing, lacking portability, reduces maintainability, and verges on intentional obfuscation

Because

Hiding complexity behind built-in 'tricks' of each language is clever at first and devastating later. if the subject is complex, like str can be undefined type, str can be null, str can be defined, not null, but blank, YOU the programmer must be explicit how you want deal with this. at the point of usage. not buried in some docs on the JavaScript API

Also note that many of these pros and cons also apply to excessive use of operator overloading, which this is a special case of, basically.

Answer (score 2):

**Advantages:** You save two seconds of coding time having to type less.

**Disadvantages:** Code is less intention-evident, making you waste the two seconds you saved having to carefully read and mind-evaluate the line of code everytime you come across it.

Comment: It takes you two whole seconds to write `!= null`?

Comment: i'd go even further.  saves you two seconds it would have taken to consider what you you want to do in the exceptional case when someone passes you a null, and defers it, with interest, until you are deploying ( or porting ) and still haven't thought about null(s) but now it costs 2^10 seconds.

Comment: @AndyzSmith You are right. I wouldn't want the flight control software of a plane I'm a passenger of to evaluate empty strings to false.

Comment: I personally don't agree empty strings converting to false is less intention-evident or makes people waste time mind-evaluating. I personally have never had to evaluate for 2 seconds a single variable as an if condition, but I have paused a time or two making sure I didn't misunderstand multiple conditions testing for emtpy strings, false, 0, null, etc. In languages where "" is false, if you have an if statement with a single variable and your intention is NOT to test for null, false, AND empty strings, it's a logic error. I'm not saying though that empty strings are best converted to false.

Comment: @dallin you're just hiding stuff.  sometimes it's good to hide, like in a loose script prototype.  My objections generally rise from the inevitable and poorly thought out transition of working prototype code into faux, production code.  Code that breaks as soon as you move outside your deevlopment crib and get a null string from some kind of Web service with different semantics for marhsalling it's parameters to you.  and your code is hard to debug, beause it works.  but it's inserting crap into the databas, because your string test evaluates to false automatically;unintentionally

Comment: @AndyzSmith I agree with what you're saying.  I've used both styles of languages extensively and in actual practice, I've personally found actual bugs of this kind pretty rare and not too difficult to troubleshoot when you run into them (assuming you do run into them instead of your customers).  I also think it makes code easier to read, as it's closer to psuedocode.  At the same time, there are problems and frustrations that arise like you're talking about, so I can see both sides.  I'm personally fine with either style but probably prefer "" to be true.

Comment: @dallin true dat.  for me, empty evaluating to boolean always leaves a bug in the last place you'd expect; routines that have been tested repeatedly and are **working**.  you waste a lot of time testing new or changed code, the typical sage advice. so in a big, integrated, multi variable debugging problem, it's a bit of a nightmare to find out that you're simply falling through to false somewhere that is supposed to be bulletproof already

Answer (score 0):

Consider this pseudo-code:

```
print "First name: " + firstname
if middlename:
  print "Middle name: " + middlename
print "Last name: " + lastname
```

This and many related cases is where "empty string is false-ish" is useful. Keep in mind that direct evaluation of non-boolean values as boolean is *usually* restricted to script-ish languages that where build with user interfaces in mind.

Comment: Did you mean to say "false-ish"?  To rephrase your answer, are you saying, "Because you can write less"?

Comment: @tieTYT: yes, of course (fixed it). Yes: less typing is pretty much what the whole "allow non-boolean expressions in places where boolean makes sense" is all about. Because you could always just make the "real" condition explicit.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Well, the origin of that practice is from languages like C (or perhaps an older language, that I don't know) where there *was* no boolean type, you always used an integer or some other numeric type to represent a boolean instead as a hack.  Since a pointer is also a numeric type, with the zero value being the null pointer, this (unfortunately) resulted in the practice of relying on `if(pointer)` being a null check.  Because the convention became so widely used it seems other languages allowed the syntax, while others choose to prevent it when adding a `Boolean` type.